# How can I count the number of columns a value has after a Where?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I need to execute a query where I have to show the title of the film and the avg valoration from the top 5 most rated films THAT HAVE OVER 2000 VOTES.

To execute that Query I dispose from the following tables (values have been already imported):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Film CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE Film(
  id_film INT,
  title VARCHAR(255),
  year INT,
  PRIMARY KEY(id_film)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS User CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE User (
  id_user INT,
  gender VARCHAR(255),
  postal_code VARCHAR(255),
  id_ocupation INT, 
  PRIMARY KEY(id_user),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_ocupation) REFERENCES Ocupation(id_ocupation),
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS User_Film;
CREATE TABLE User_Film (
  id_film INT, 
  id_user INT, 
  rating INT,
  timestamp INT,
  PRIMARY KEY(id_film, id_user),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_film) REFERENCES Film(id_film),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES User(id_user)
);
```

And I have tried executing the following query. The query works fine but, how can I filter the output by the number of valorations?

```
select title, avg(rating)
from User U,
     Film P,
     User_Film UP
where UP.id_user = U.id_user
  AND UP.id_film = P.id_film
group by title
order by avg(rating) desc
limit 5;
```

Also I guessed (as there's no field in any table named number_of_valorations or something similar) that the number of valorations is the amount of users who rates the same film.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `having` clause:

```
select title, avg(rating)
from User U join
     User_Film UP
     on UP.id_user = U.id_user join
     Film P 
     on UP.id_film = P.id_film
group by title
having count(*) >= 2000
order by avg(rating) desc
limit 5;
```

Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.